# Cache using ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, hashmap

I have the following code:

```
public class Cache {

    private final Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public Object get(Object key) {

        Object value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new SomeObject();
            map.put(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

My question is:
The `put` and `get` methods of the map are thread safe, but since the whole block in not synchronized - could multiple threads add a the same key twice?

Comment: @Mureinik's answer is a specific example of a more general principle:  Building a system entirely out of thread-safe components does nothing to make the system as a whole thread safe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`put` and `get` are thread safe in the sense that calling them from different threads cannot corrupt the data structure (as, e.g., is possible with a normal `java.util.HashMap`).

However, since the block is not synchronized, you may still have multiple threads adding the same key:
Both threads may pass the `null` check, one adds the key and returns its value, and then the second will override that value with a new one and returns it.

Answer (score 16):

As of Java 8, you can also prevent this addition of duplicate keys with:

```
public class Cache {

    private final Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public Object get(Object key) {

        Object value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, (key) -> {
          return new SomeObject();
        });

        return value;
    }
}
```

The [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) state:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
>   to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
>   into this map unless null. **The entire method invocation is performed
>   atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key**. Some
>   attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be
>   blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be
>   short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of
>   this map.

Answer (score 3):

> could multiple threads add a the same key twice?

Yes, they could. To fix this problem you can:

1) Use `putIfAbsent` method instead of put. It very fast but unnecessary SomeObject instances can be created.

2) Use double checked locking:

```
Object value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
    synchronized (map) {
        value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new SomeObject();
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
return value;
```

Lock is much slower, but only necessary objects will be created

Answer (score 3):

you could also combine checking and putIfAbsent such as:

```
Object value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
    return map.putIfAbsent(key, new SomeObject());
}
return value;
```

thereby reducing the unneccessary new objects to cases where new entries are introduced in the short time between the check and the putIfAbsent.

If you are feeling lucky and reads vastly outnumber writes to your map, you can also create your own copy-on-write map similar to CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: null is returned when cache miss.